# vb.net listview won't accept color settings

Tags: vb.net, listviewitem

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
    For Each rec As DataRow In rex
        Dim entry As New ListViewItem({rec("Project"), rec("effort")})
        entry.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
        entry.ForeColor = Color.Ivory
        BreakdownListview.Items.Add(entry)
    Next
```

The 2 color settings are completely ignored. The control comes up with white background and black text.

Comment: If the data is already in a datatable, why make copies of it to display in a listview at all.  Use the DataTable as the DataSource for a DGV; one line of code and not copying of data.  Otherwise cannot repro

Comment: There is no datatable. rex is an ArrayList of DataRows I extracted from a query. Never has more than 6 or 7 elements. Seems an overkill for a datatable but I'll look into it. Thanks. This assumes, of course, that a DGV will let me control the 2 color settings better than this listview does.

Comment: ArrayList is antiquated as well.  When you run the query, you can fill a DT using `cmd.ExecuteReader` and is a perfect container for db results.  One more line of code will create all the column the DGV needs and display the row data in it.  it has oodles and oodles of properties for finetuning the display.

Comment: I'm offering this only because I don't see any problem with the code above. Is this the only thing adding to this listview? I ask because you are only affecting the items this block of code adds to the listview and anything preexisting would have the default colors. Is it possible that what this code is doing is adding further down the listview and you need to scroll down to see it? Also, have you set a break point on this block of code to ensure that the data coming to your listview is from this specific block of code?

Comment: Re ArrayList being antiquated: doesn't surprise me. Been a gazillion years since I wrote in Basic. This is actually a minor point in my app since the data is there and readable, just not as pretty as I'd like. So could be a while before I have another go at it. I do like the idea of the DGV.

Comment: Re the listview being long: no, hardly ever more than half a dozen entries, so no scrolling at all. And yes, I set a breakpoint and it claims everything is  as it should be - just doesn't work out that way.

Comment: One oddity I should have mentioned. I first tried to set the listview's background and foreground colors and the foreground color did work. Kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

The BackColor and ForeColor are ignored if the item is selected, your best bet is to set OwnerDraw to true in the ListView and paint the items yourself.

```
Private Sub ListView1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawSubItem
    If e.Item.Selected Then
        Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(Color.SlateGray)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, e.Bounds)
        Brush.Dispose()
    Else
        Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(e.SubItem.BackColor)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, e.Bounds)
        Brush.Dispose()
    End If

    e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
    e.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Bounds)
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawColumnHeader(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawColumnHeader
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm. I do appreciate your effort but this is way too much code just to set a couple color properties. Also, this is not about an item being selected. I just wanted all entries to have those colors. Thanks though.